# Linear Algebra Text Book

Tags: linear-algebra, teaching, textbook-recommendation

In our department we do not like our current linear algebra book and so we would want to find a better book. This is for the first course in linear algebra and the title of the course is 
Elementary Linear Algebra.  The book should have at least the following things

-- An online homework system
-- A good emphasis on proofs in the exercises
-- Should introduce linear transformations earlier
-- Some applications

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help

Comment: This question is not about research and should be closed.

Comment: @NateEldredge But I thought that some questions relating to mathematical pedagogy (or "teaching maths in the trenches:) are on topic here? I am not sure about the present question

Comment: I changed the tag now to textbook recommendation. Is that good for this kind of post? Let me know. Thank you

Comment: Check David Lay's "Linear algebra and its applications" taught with MyMathLab (online hw system).

Comment: I agree with @YemonChoi -- this kind of question has been honored in the past without controversy. It's the type of question that professional mathematicians ask of one another. Perhaps a meta should be opened?

Comment: Meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/797/2926

Comment: While not a duplicate, there might be very heavy overlap with the previous question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16994/linear-algebra-texts

Comment: "Should introduce linear transformations earlier" --- earlier than what?

Comment: What is meant by the inclusion in a book of "an online homework system"?

Comment: Could you also include what the syllabus needs to be? There could be plenty of different textbooks satisfying the current conditions but missing a key part of the syllabus.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Basically what I meant was, introduce linear transformations as early as possible. Some books wait until the very last chapters for no reasons and we don't want that.

Comment: @Dan Fox: basically something like Webassign, or my Mathlab etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra Texts?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16994/linear-algebra-texts)